# How to move cursor position using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a Liferay 6.2 project. In Liferay, they used Vaadin. When I click on a button it opens with a different iframe. I can code that all functionality. Now I want to move the cursor to the iframe element using WebDriver. Because when I move mouse to the iframe checkbox after that my automate script can run. I want to automate a script to move the mouse pointer to the the element.

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't work.

1) using `Action moveToElement`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("element1")).click();
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("element2"))).click().perform();
```

2) using `mouseMove`

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element xpath"));
Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) element;
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevice) driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseMove(hoverItem.getCoordinates());
```

> error: getting a error in ((HasInputDevice) driver).
>   HasInputDevice cannot be resolved to a type

3)

```
Locatable hoverItem = (Locatable) driver.findElement(By.xpath("element xpath"));
int y = hoverItem.getCoordinates().getLocationOnScreen().getY();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+y+");");
```

> error: getting a error in getLocationOnScreen()
>   The method getLocationOnScreen() is undefined for the type Coordinates

4)

```
Point coordinates = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element xpath")).getLocation();
Robot robot = new Robot();
WebElement markNews = driver.findElement(By.xpath("element xpath"));
markNews.click();
robot.mouseMove(coordinates.x,coordinates.y+80);
```

This does not work.

I just want to move cursor point to the iframe locator.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly select iframe using:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("frameId")));
```

Now by using selenium web driver you can perform any operation in this iframe.

To move back to main window you just need to :

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: i dont want to switch frame. i have already done that stuff. i need to move cursor(mouse pointer).

Comment: If your site support jquery then you can try selenium javascript executor with this code $(document)
       .mouseXPos(e.pageX + 50)
       .mouseYPos(e.pageY + 50);

Answer (score 1):

It's:

```
HasInputDevices
```

(devices is plural)

Answer (score 1):

I thought your first example:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("element2"))).click().perform();
```

Should read:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("element2"))).build().perform().click();
```

That is, you first find the element, then build a series of actions to perform on it (in this case just one) then perform those actions (now the mouse should be over the element) then click

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called Sikuli which integrates directly into Selenium:

[Sikuli Install Info](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver)

Example Code:

```
import org.sikuli.script.Button;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Location;
import org.sikuli.script.Match;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

Screen screen = new Screen();
// Find where you want to move the mouse and set a location
Location wheelPoint = new Location(1000, 800);
// You can always just get center as well
// Location wheelCenter = screen.getCenter();
try {
    screen.wheel(wheelPoint, Button.WHEEL_DOWN, steps);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Assert.fail("Mouse did not move to desired location");
}
```