# Selenium Autosuggestions Xpath Java Exception

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, autocomplete

I need help with below Java code with Selenium. I am trying click on the first item on auto suggestions list on site http://booking.com. I have failed to do only on booking.com. It works for Google Autosuggestion list, Yahoo Autosuggestion list but, on Booking.com

Below is the code -

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class BookingDotCom_Test {

    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http:\\booking.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='destination']")).sendKeys(
                "Mumbai");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ui-active-menuitem']")).click();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no id named 'ui-active-menuitem', there is however 'aria-activedescendant' named that way.
So try perhaps "//*[@aria-activedescendant='ui-active-menuitem']".
Either way, that's not the first item, that's the whole menu.
if you want the first item only, you could do something like

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@aria-activedescendant='ui-active-menuitem']//a")).get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is `id='ui-active-menuitem'` on the page. However this Id is under hover effect means  appear only when you over this item. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759348/how-to-move-mouse-pointercursor-position-using-webdriver) for explanation how to move mouse with webdriver. Also I suggest to use `Action` as described in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
        driver.get("http://www.booking.com/");

        driver.findElement(By
                .xpath("//input[@id='destination']")).sendKeys("Mumbai");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

        WebElement ul = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@aria-activedescendant='ui-active-menuitem' and contains(@style, 'display: block;')]")));

        List<WebElement> recommendations = ul.findElements(By
                .xpath("li/a"));

        System.out.println(recommendations.size());

        for (WebElement recommendation : recommendations) {
            System.out.println(recommendation.getText());
        }
```

Result

```
5
Mumbai, Maharashtra, India 
Chhatrapati Shivaji International Airport Mumbai, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India
South Mumbai, Mumbai, Maharashtra, India 
Navi Mumbai, Maharashtra, India 
Santa Cruz (Mumbai), Maharashtra, India (Properties nearby)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help guys. It works now for me. However, I haven't used what is suggested here that is, aria-activedescendant. I still don't know what is that!

However, I did use absolute Xpath and it works absolutely fine for me. It selects the first item in menu with its full Xpath.

Regards,
Bharat.